# Cannot Call Method From Parent Class From Child Class Python

Tags: python, oop

I am wondering if this is an environment problem. I have a parent class in a file that has a method that I previously wrote "is_element_present()" When my colleague calls this method from a child class method the the method runs fine. However, when the newer method "new_parent_method" is called from the child class she gets **Attribute Error: object has no attribute new_parent_method**. What is strange is when I work with the same code pulled from the same branch on my machine I have no problems. I tried eliminating all the .pyc and **pycache** files and still we run into the same problem. Even stranger, if I erase the parent class from parent.py and then run the code again the tests will still run as if the parent class is still present. Needless to say I am perplexed. The code is below:

in the file /parent/parent_class.py I have:

```
class DNASeleniumParent(unittestTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.base = settings.base_url

    def is_element_present(self, element):
        try:
            self.get_element(element)
       except:
           return False
       return True

    def new_parent_method(self):
        print "DO SOMETHING!"
```

in /test_suite.py I have

```
from parent.parent_class import *
class TestSuite(DNASeleniumParent):
    def test_is_element_present(self):
        element = "div.somediv"
        self.get_element(element)

    def test_new_parent_method(self):
        self.new_parent_method(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Totally unrelated but 1/ dont use star imports (`from something import *`), and 2/ _never_ use bare except clauses (always specify the exception type you expect).

Comment: "I am wondering if this is an environment problem." - the answer is *yes*, it is an environment problem.

Comment: yeah I know star import bad practice will change. I knew I was going to get some flack for that.

Comment: Tom Dalton smug response was indeed correct. The problem was with the virtual environment I simply had to add the path to directory where the module that contained this class lives.